Use PCAPNG for different protocols
I have a microcontroller under test that use different peripherals that communicate using either ethernet (udp) or UART.
I want to record every messages exchanged between this microcontroller and a computer running Linux, ideally, every messages should be in a single file that I can read and extract data to analyse some behaviour.
Can I use the PCAPNG format to put UDP and UART messages in the same file? I saw the custom block, can it be used for UART messages? Is it the right tool?
